# iOS portrait only app returns from UIWebview youtube in landscape

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, landscape-portrait

I'm creating an `iOS application` and i've encountered the following problem:

The project is set to be a `portrait` mode application.
I have a `UIWebview`, which loads a webpage with a `youtube` video in it. When the video is clicked it starts in the `youtube player`. When the video changes to `landscape` mode and 'done' is clicked it returns to the `UIWebview` showing it in `landscape`.

I do receive a `NSNotification` when the video is finished but I'm not able to force `portrait` mode.

This should not be possible, how can I allow youtube to be in `landscape` but force the app to stay in `portrait` mode? Or is there another workaround?

**EDIT:**

After contact with Apple it turned out to be a bug and is reported.

Comment: How did you get the youtube player from a UIWebView to show up in landscape?

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

is  private API . I would not recommend using it.

```
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *view = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [window insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
```

is much better way i think. It forces the app to adjust its orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use NSNotification as you said and in called method use this line of code for now to force view to portrait

```
- (void)YourMethodCalledByNSNotification
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    }
}
```

Hope that Helps