# Present UIViewController in Landscape mode in Portrait only app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

My app is a portrait only. I need to present a UIViewController in Landscape mode(Reason for that is I am using Core-Plot sdk for drawing graphs on that viewcontroller, so it needs to be in landscape mode).

I tried the following methods and it work fine. But the issue is, when I dismiss the landscape viewcontroller, app cannot force to portrait mode.

http://www.sebastianborggrewe.de/only-make-one-single-view-controller-rotate/

http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/forcing-uiviewcontroller-orientation/

How can I force the app to become **portrait only** mode after dismiss the landscape viewcontroller?

This is How I presenting the landscape view controller and dismissing it.

```
 LineChartViewController *obj = [[LineChartViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LineChartViewController" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];  


- (IBAction)btnDonePressed:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

XIB of the LineChartViewController is in landscape mode.

**In simple words, My app is portrait only, and I wanted to show CorePlot hostView in landscape mode.**

Comment: i already did this type of Functionality in one of my app,  my app is portrait only and in my application  i show one view in landscape Mode,  and its working fine i Just  set the NIB File in landscape Mode but the method  using for  presenting the  landscapeview is different

Comment: Use this for presenting the landscapeview                                               LineChartViewController *obj = [[LineChartViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LineChartViewController" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

Comment: I wrote the answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30812053/893872

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I could solve the issue by rotating the CorePlot hostView. The solution isn't the perfect for the the question described, but I'd like to put my solution here, since it solved my problem

```
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewGraphBack.bounds];
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
[self.viewGraphBack addSubview:self.hostView];

CGAffineTransform transform =
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));

viewGraphBack.transform = transform;

viewGraphBack.frame = CGRectMake(-285, 0, 568, 320);

[self.view addSubview:viewGraphBack];
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of workaround works for me (temporary pushing fake model view controller), called after other view controller which introduces new orientation is demised:

```
- (void)doAWorkaroudnOnUnwantedRotation {
  // check if is workaround nesesery:
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
    double delayInSeconds = 0.7;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      UIViewController *fake = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
      UIViewController *rootController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
      [rootController presentModalViewController: fake animated: NO];
      [fake dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Parent viewcontroller in `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` mode & current viewcontroller should be in `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` or `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` in that case you may use device orientation changing delegate & a few codes in `viewdidload`

In ViewDidLoad

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

& implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` delegate in ViewController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Like this. Assure that landscape mode must be checked in from target settings.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write this category in your project

```
 #import "UINavigationController+ZCNavigationController.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (ZCNavigationController)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
@end
```

And in your viewcontroller where you need Landscape

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```