# How to present UIViewController to landscape and dismiss to portrait without ever rotating previous ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, screen-orientation

I cannot share any code or images about the project, that's why I will try my best to explain the situation.

The app is forced portrait mode but there is only one case where I need to present in landscape mode. When I present and dismiss the landscape ViewController, views in the previous ViewController get buggy. It happens especially with UITableViews. If I am not mistaken, it's happening because when I present a ViewController in landscape mode, other ViewControllers presented in UIWindow also rotate in the background.

I tried to use a second UIWindow and present the landscape ViewController in the second window. I thought it would only rotate ViewControllers in the second UIWindow but it seems it rotates the main window as well.

Is there any way to force a view controller from rotating ever so that I can keep previous ViewControllers in portrait mode all the time or is there a way to make tableViews prone to this behaviour?

Note: I may present the landscape ViewController in portrait mode and manage views by myself to look like it's in landscape mode but I would prefer a more elegant solution if possible. I also checked out this thread ([Present UIViewController in Landscape mode in Portrait only app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056664/present-uiviewcontroller-in-landscape-mode-in-portrait-only-app)) but not sure if it would solve this problem because I want my landscape mode to rotate left-right properly.

Comment: Forcing views into portrait / landscape orientation can result in a "clunky" interface... particularly when a user runs your app in multi-tasking mode on an iPad. Depending on what your **content** is, managing the views yourself might be the "elegant solution." You say: *"I cannot share any code or images about the project"* -- but I expect you could at least describe whether the "landscape mode" controller content is static, dynamic, interactive, etc.

Comment: @DonMag Landscape controller has an AVPlayer and custom controls for it. UIView elements should stay in their place except for rotating right or left in landscape mode and most of them are interactive.